# Control class and id attributes of matplotlib .svg figures?

Tags: python, css, matplotlib, svg

I want the .svg figures on my website to follow the site's css theme. To do so, I need predictable ID or CLASS attributes for each plotted item, but I do not know how to control the attributes that matplotlib chooses when saving svg figures.

Is there a way to manually control the ID or CLASS from matplotlib for each item in the plot before the svg figure is saved (using plt.savefig)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the gid attribute to the plot command, for example:

```
plt.plot(x, y, gid="fitted_curve")
```